# Subscripts in Axis title

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-charts

How can create subscripts in axis title in excel. When right clicking on it. No font tab appears after format title option.
However, I add subscripts excel cells using the above.
Though copying this subscript text to axis title removes the subscript.

Comment: What do you mean by *subscripts*? Show some samples. There are some high Unicode characters that might work.

Comment: For example in latex x_{1} .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put subscripted numbers into your axis titles, a full set of subscripted characters representing ₀ through ₉ are available with Unicode U+2080 to U+2089 (8320 to 8329 dec). You can generate these high Unicode characters with the following key sequences.

1. For a ₀ (U+2080) hold down one of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys.
2. Tap <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> on the numpad.
3. Release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

These characters are also available to be copied to the clipboard from the **Character Map** utility (e.g. *charmap.exe*). Locate and choose the character you want to copy to the clipboard then click <kbd>Select</kbd> and <kbd>Copy</kbd>. Go back to where you wanted to insert the character and *Paste* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

Example: latex x₁

Comment: Setting up a series of AutoCorrect entries would also be an option. These could be run in a VBA loop for both subscript and superscript.